# Sql server 2012 Trigger: Convert row to xml and write to column error

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, ddl, audit

I am having an issue writing a trigger which is supposed to convert a row on a table to XML and writing it to a single column in another table. The Whenever a new row is inserted into this table (person.address) I want this trigger to send the row (converted to XML) to another table (audit.table) Here is my Trigger.

```
       Create trigger [Person].[sPerson] ON [Person].[Address_s] for INSERT AS
begin
    DECLARE @xml XML;
    SET @xml =  
    (
      SELECT [AddressID], [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City], [StateProvinceID], [SpatialLocation.ToString()], [PostalCode], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate]

      FROM INSERTED
      FOR XML PATH('Inserted')
    );
    insert into AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Audit.Table(AuditXml) VALUES (@xml);
end
```

My error is

FOR XML does not support CLR types - cast CLR types explicitly into one of the supported types in FOR XML queries.

I have a column on the audit.table called AuditXml of type XML. It seems to think AuditXML is invalid. Thank you.

Comment: You don't want this `[SpatialLocation.ToString()]`. Change to `[SpatialLocation].ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the column `SpatialLocation` in `Person.Address` that makes your `for xml` query to fail.

`SpatialLocation` is of type `geography` and that is a CLR type.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way in which I can convert the geography type? or even exclude it?

Comment: @EPOColla You can use `SpatialLocation.ToString()`. You can not use `select *`. Instead you have to specify all columns you need.

Comment: I have updated my SQL. I amhaving the same issue, Am I using the .tosting incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: @EPOColla did you see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020650/sql-server-2012-trigger-convert-row-to-xml-and-write-to-column-error/21022056?noredirect=1#comment31599232_21020650)?

Comment: Thank you Very much. That has worked. I hope I carry you to 70k :)

Comment: I have edited the question. for some reason the PrevValue returning Null.

Comment: @EPOColla If there are no rows in the deleted table it will be null. Your really should not change the question. Ask a new one instead. My answer looks like it has nothing to do with the question any longer.

Comment: OK good point. apologies. I will change that back. Thank you.